# Load multiple csv into ORACLE database using SQLLDR with NAMES of the loaded files

Tags: oracle, import, sql-loader

I need to load a banch of .csv files from a certain directory. Problem is I also need filenames as they contain information.

I'm managed to load files using similar command:

```
FOR %c in (C:\tmp\loader\*.csv) DO (
   c:\oracle\db\dbhome_1\BIN\sqlldr <user>@<sid>l/<password> control=C:\tmp\loader\loader.ctl data=%c
   )
```

C:\tmp\loader\loader.ctl is (again it's an example)

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=0,SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
  APPEND  
  INTO TABLE scott.td_region_position
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$$' TRAILING NULLCOLS
  ( POSITION_KEY,
    POSITION_NAME ,
    CHANNEL,
    LVL,
    IS_PARTNER,
    MARKET_CODE
  )
```

Can I add the name of files somehow to the loaded information?

Comment: Can you just - inside your loop - make a copy of each file, append the name to each line, and use that for the load? Which is a scripting question, really, not a SQL\*Loader question. But I don't think there's a direct way. If you were using an external table you could use the preprocessor directive, but basically the same thing - except the temporary file wouldn't have to be written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Just generate temporary control file with `CONSTANT` for file name.

For example, gen_ctl.bat:

```
@echo off
echo OPTIONS (ERRORS=0,SKIP=1)
echo LOAD DATA
echo   APPEND  
echo   INTO TABLE scott.td_region_position
echo   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$$' TRAILING NULLCOLS
echo   ( POSITION_KEY,
echo     POSITION_NAME ,
echo     CHANNEL,
echo     LVL,
echo     IS_PARTNER,
echo     MARKET_CODE,
echo     FILE_NAME constant '%1'
echo    )
```

then run it in your loop with filename in argument. Example:

```
C:\tmp>gen_ctl.bat my-file.dat >temp.ctl

C:\tmp>type temp.ctl
OPTIONS (ERRORS=0,SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
  APPEND
  INTO TABLE scott.td_region_position
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$$' TRAILING NULLCOLS
  ( POSITION_KEY,
    POSITION_NAME ,
    CHANNEL,
    LVL,
    IS_PARTNER,
    MARKET_CODE,
    FILE_NAME constant 'my-file.dat'
   )
```

and pass this `temp.ctl` to sqlldr